# How to open Visual Studio exe's(VS2008,VS2010,VS2012,VS2013) with some projects by programming in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008

Now i am creating one test studio in c# to check my projects are build succeeded in all versions(2008,2010,2012,2013).
By this studio. if i click VS2008 button means,  it will open VS2008 exe with my projects. By this i would like to ensure build success in all versions.

Any one could you please provide your suggestion to me?

Comment: You are on the wrong track with this.  Opening a .csproj file with another version of VS than the one that created it is going to cause the project to be converted.  You do not want that to happen, you'll lose the original project and can't open it anymore in an older VS version.  Pursuing this doesn't make a lot of sense but you will need to keep separate .csproj files for each VS version.  Just give them different names.  VS2012 is the first version that can open old projects without converting them so you'll have some leeway.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Visual Studio doesn't necessarily match the version of .NET framework you are compiling with, and you don't need VS to do the compilation.

Just invoke the correct compiler for each version - 2.0, 4.0, etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(v=vs.80).aspx

If you are working with one of those project types that the compiler can't handle (setup and deployment), then you can use the `devenv.exe` command line for the appropriate VS version and add the `/build` [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx).

Comment: Jack- I will check this and let u know